# Not able to inject @Service and @Contract dependency in my resource class

Tags: jersey, tomcat8, java-ee-7, hk2

On base of the guide from this blog, [Roll your own Auto Discovery with Jersey and HK2](http://www.indestructiblevinyl.com/2016/07/25/roll-your-own-auto-discovery-in-jersey-and-hk2.html), I have the follow *resource POJO*:

```
@Path("Test")
public class TestResource {
    @Inject
    private TestService service;
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Set<Test> getTests() {
        return service.getAllTests();
    }
}
```

The `TestService`:

```
@Contract
public interface TestService {
    public Set<Test> getAllTests();
}
```

The `TestServiceImpl`

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

    @Override
    public Set<Test> getAllTests() {
        Set<Test> tests = new HashSet<>();
        Test c = new Test();
        c.setName("test");
        tests.add(c);
        return tests;
    }
}
```

The Jersey dependency in `pom.xml` is of version 2.25.1

```
   <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
         <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
         <artifactId>hk2</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.0-b36</version>
     </dependency>
```

In order to make Jersey scan the @Service and @Contract classes **automatically**, I used the `inhabitant-generator` plugin with version 2.5.0-b36:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
  <artifactId>hk2-inhabitant-generator</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.0-b36</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate-inhabitants</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

There is the corresponding `Feature` implementation:

```
public class AutoServiceDiscovery implements Feature {

@Override
public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
    ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorProvider.getServiceLocator(context);
    DynamicConfigurationService dcs = locator.getService(DynamicConfigurationService.class);
    Populator populator = dcs.getPopulator();
    try {
        populator.populate(new ClasspathDescriptorFileFinder(this.getClass().getClassLoader()),
                new DuplicatePostProcessor());
    } catch (IOException | MultiException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

And it is indeeded registered through my `ResourceConfig` class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/*")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApplicationConfig() {
        packages("resources");
        register(new AutoServiceDiscovery());
}
```

}
However, I send request to the `/test`, got the following error:

```
MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for 
injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=TestService,parent=TestResource,qualifiers=
{},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1947073589)
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of 
rx.practice.ee.jaxrs.resources.TestResource errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on 
rx.practice.ee.jaxrs.resources.TestResource

org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:89)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:250)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
...
```

**Question: Anyone knows why the @Service class cannot be injected? I am using Tomcat server**

Comment: My first question is whether or not you are definitely using the hk2-inhabitant-generator in your build.  If so, can you show us the build file and also can you take a look at (or post) the produced META-INF/hk2-locator files?  Those files contain the service definitions created during your build

Comment: @jwells131313 Thanks for your comment, the problem is indeeded related to the location of the generated locator files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of days research on the source code of `inhabitat-generator`, I figured out that in case of web application package,`war`, the *locator* file is not generated in `META-INF/hk2-locator` as demonstracted in the [HK2 Inhabitant Generator office site](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/inhabitant-generator.html) in case of using `jar` as deployment package. The [source code of AbstractInhabitantsGeneratorMojo.java](https://github.com/rxue/hk2/blob/master/maven-plugins/hk2-inhabitant-generator/src/main/java/org/jvnet/hk2/generator/maven/AbstractInhabitantsGeneratorMojo.java) told that in case of `war`, *locator* files are generated in `hk2-locator`, and this is not mentioned in the [HK2 Inhabitant Generator office site](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/inhabitant-generator.html).

However, when constructing the [ClasspathDescriptorFileFinder](https://github.com/javaee/hk2/blob/master/hk2-api/src/main/java/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/ClasspathDescriptorFileFinder.java) without the directory names argument in the bootstrap class, `AutoServiceDiscovery`, it is only compatible with `jar` as deployment package, meaning it is only finding files in `META-INF/hk2-locator`.

So the better solution would be not to use `inhabitant-generator` plugin but the `metadata-generator` dependency, which is an *annotation processor* at compile time and, it is proved *out-of-the-box*.

If someone is persistent to using this plugin, he/she could create his/her own `ClasspathDescriptorFileFinder` so that it is able to find *locator* files from `hk2-locator`

Last but not least, I also tried to use the `inhabitants-generator` plugin's options to generate the *locator* files in `hk2-locator`, but this seems to be next to impossible as well

Comment: oh yeah, the metadata-generator is definitely better